# Sending S/Mime message to BizTalk - but Biztalk cannot decode it

Tags: powershell, biztalk, smime

I am trying to send an S/Mime message to BizTalk but it doesn't seem able to receive it.

I can encrypt and decrypt a message from my code (I'm working in Powershell as a proof of concept ) using the BizTalk certificate and the System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs classes. However when I endeavour to pass it to BizTalk directly I see this message:

```
There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: 
[... application name ... ]
Source: "MIME/SMIME decoder" 
Receive Port: "ReceiveEncryptedPort" 
URI: "FORMATNAME:DIRECT=OS:.\PRIVATE$\encrypted_queue"
Reason: There was an authentication failure. "Failed to decode the S/MIME message. The S/MIME message may not be valid.".
```

I can create a message that is consumed correctly if I do it from within BizTalk ( no use to man nor beast, of course ) and have found that the message is formatted thus:

```
Mime Message with Base64 Encoded encrypted content.
    => Decrypts to Mime Message with Base64 Encoded Unicode content.
    => Decodes to message content.
```

However, when I recreate the same pattern with my PowerShell script, the above exception arises. If I send the exact literal of the working message created in BizTalk it appears to work correctly, which implies that there is a problem with my encoding elsewhere, but as I have copied all the headers from the working message to use in the non-working ones ( except I add a new Content-Id ) I find it very hard to understand what the difference is that BizTalk is failing.

A sample message looks like this:

```
Content-ID: {28c96069-f9a4-4cb3-9587-f1cb229dd54b} 
Bcc: MIME-Version 1.0
Content-type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

MIICggYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIICczCCAm8CAQAxgcgwgcUCAQAwLjAaMRgwFgYDVQQDEw93d3cuZGxy
    -- More Base64 Encoded Text --
FZ6L1V+AylyzI7H+P0pmhA9yRl2Q/OiqRnNQ6tmw0mXkZxinuVryVha5aPkVhF19LJiS+vbjVWTF
jCDLdfJh4jMmOHlAiVOPc+TAIA==
```

I am wondering whether it is possible that somehow the text is being encoded wrong by Powershell - using ASCII instead of Unicode or something - but that seems a little tenuous and makes BizTalk seem unbelievably fragile.

The code I am using to encrypt the message is like this:

```
function encryptWithCms( $text,  $certPath="cert:\CurrentUser\TrustedPeople", $certName="CN=myCertificate" )
{
   Add-Type -assemblyName "System.Security";
   $cert = Get-ChildItem $certPath | Where-Object { $_.Subject -eq $certName };
   $unicode = new-object System.Text.UnicodeEncoding;
   #this part copied directly from the internal message that BizTalk will accept.
   $pretext = @'
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-16"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Description: body

'@;
   $pretext+= "`r`n";
    $text = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String( $unicode.GetBytes( $text ));
    $text = $pretext+$text;
    Write-Host $text;
   $encryptData = $unicode.GetBytes( $text );
   $contentInfo = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.ContentInfo (,$encryptData);
   $cmsRecipient = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsRecipient $cert;
   $envelopedCms = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.EnvelopedCms $contentInfo;
   $envelopedCms.Encrypt($cmsRecipient);
   return  [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($envelopedCms.Encode());
}
```

To turn it into an S/Mime message I do something very similar, prepending the headers from a heredoc type string and pushing the encrypted text on the end as illustrated in the message above. I drop them into 72 character blocks for readability, which is the same thing BizTalk does and which doesn't affect the decryption when run through PowerShell.

Any thoughts on what else I would need to do in order to get these requests working would be welcome.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the output from your Powershell script and the equivalent BizTalk encoded message to check for differences?

Comment: @NickHeppleston have indeed, this is how I made the list of what each step of the encoding/encryption contains. The biggest difference I can see is that at the innermost level of encoding, where the actual message data itself is base64 encoded, it looks different encoded with Powershell to how it does encoded by Biztalk, even though it looks the same decoded from both.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the below issue is due to the input provided is not MIME format.Check the input provided, it accept the Base64 format.

```
Error: There was an authentication failure. "Failed to decode the S/MIME message. The S/MIME message may not be valid.".
```

We will face the issue if the format of MIME message is wrong.

Comment: As you can see, the text is created by `System.Convert.ToBase64String`  so as far as Powershell ( or every other application I have used ) is concerned it _is_ base64 encoded, but the same text appears to be different when encoded by Biztalk. If you can shed any light on this it would be helpful.